# Plug-in Install troubles

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I tried to install following plug-ins into QGIS2.8.(My PC is Win8, 64bit.)

```
*Table Manager
*Group Stat
```

But error message says "`The Plug-is is broken`. Python said:
`GroupStats instance has no attribute 'localePath'`. (In case of "table manager" plug-in, same message appeared)

Do I need to install anything?
I would like to know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you have a python version installed outside of QGIS, that is in your PATH variable? That might leed to conflicts. The table manager works fine for me on Windows 7.

Comment: Thank you AndreJ.  My PC installed ArcGIS, Does this lead conflict of python?

Comment: If you right-click on the Windows icon, open a command window, type python and python starts, you will get conflicts. I don't know how ARCGIS will behave if you remove that python version. QGIS has its own, it gets incorporated only when you start it, or the OSGEO4W shell.